# Load ruby script into another ruby script

Tags: ruby

I need to define a function in a script that is loading another script, and use it in the script being loaded. For example:

main file:

```
require 'file'
def FunctionA()
    #define function here
end
```

file.rb:

```
FunctionA()
```

I cannot move the definition to the file being included. Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: I am not. The one being included is un-compressed using Zlib. The other one I am writing. Also, ruby seems to not count my comments as lines or something, as my line numbers are always off. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the use case presented in your question right now, just move `require 'file'` to the end.

```
def FunctionA()
    #define function here
end

require 'file'
```

Comment: This was my first thought. Does the error "uninitialized constant Font (NameError)" mean it is looking for a variable, not a function?

Comment: Wanted to discuss with you Ruby JSON class.. Could you propose a time, when you will be free ?